# Get value of math operations SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, set-returning-functions

I have a problem on this query, how do I use the result of the query contained in `CostoUnitario` field.

I see better explain, after: ... **as CostoUnitario**..

I should insert **,CostoUnitario* Quantita**

How can I do?

**CODE:**

```
SELECT Capitolo.Descrizione,SottoCapitolo.Descrizione,
SottoCapitolo.Immagine,
SottoCapitolo.DescrizioneEstesa,
SottoCapitolo.Quantita,
ROUND(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)+(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)/100)*PercentualeMargine)+(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)/100)*PercentualeUtile)+(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)/100)*PercentualeSpeseGenerali)),0)
 as CostoUnitario 
FROM Preventivo inner join Capitolo on Preventivo.IdPreventivo = Capitolo.IdPreventivo inner join SottoCapitolo on SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo = Capitolo.IdCapitolo order by Capitolo.Descrizione
```

**IMAGE:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must repeat last operation and add * Quantita.

> SELECT A, B, C, (A + B) AS AB, (A + B) * C AS ABC

```
SELECT Capitolo.Descrizione,SottoCapitolo.Descrizione,
SottoCapitolo.Immagine,
SottoCapitolo.DescrizioneEstesa,
SottoCapitolo.Quantita,
ROUND(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)+(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)/100)*PercentualeMargine)+(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)/100)*PercentualeUtile)+(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)/100)*PercentualeSpeseGenerali)),0)
 as CostoUnitario,
ROUND(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)+(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)/100)*PercentualeMargine)+(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)/100)*PercentualeUtile)+(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)/100)*PercentualeSpeseGenerali)),0) * SottoCapitolo.Quantita
FROM Preventivo inner join Capitolo on Preventivo.IdPreventivo = Capitolo.IdPreventivo inner join SottoCapitolo on SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo = Capitolo.IdCapitolo order by Capitolo.Descrizione
```

You can avoid it by calculating this values in presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible query, if you don't want to write the same line again would be:

```
select *, CostoUnitario * Quantita
FROM
(
    SELECT Capitolo.Descrizione as CapDescrizione,
        SottoCapitolo.Descrizione,  
        SottoCapitolo.Immagine,
        SottoCapitolo.DescrizioneEstesa,
        SottoCapitolo.Quantita,
        ROUND(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)+(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)/100)*PercentualeMargine)+(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)/100)*PercentualeUtile)+(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)/100)*PercentualeSpeseGenerali)),0)
         as CostoUnitario 
        FROM Preventivo 
        inner join Capitolo on Preventivo.IdPreventivo = Capitolo.IdPreventivo 
        inner join SottoCapitolo on SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo = Capitolo.IdCapitolo 
) as Co
order by CapDescrizione
```